# Translating a curl post request into python-requests does not work

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"message": 
"test"}' http://localhost:5000/members
```

This is my old code which was working as a command (returns a 200). now i want to write a python skript for that using requests. I am trying this:

```
header = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/members", data={"message": "test"}, headers=header)
```

Which returns an 400. Why? How can i fix that? Its btw a flask rest api running on that port.

Comment: try `json` instead of `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to send the data without actually combining it. You just need to surround the {} with '.

```
header = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/members", data='{"message": "test"}', headers=header)
```